# how to connect 2 applications through a pseudo serial port with socat

Tags: linux, serial-port, virtual, virtualbox

I am developing an embedded application. It will be running on a full-fledged embedded linux, but will be controlled through commands arriving from the serial port from a windows host.

during the debug phase, this windows host is running in a virtual machine and the embedded application is run locally. As such I would like for these 2 to communicate normally as if a normal usb (to serial) cable was connected between them.

How do I go about it? I have heard of the notion of pseudo ports (/dev/ptyXX) but haven't found any C tutorial to go about it.

I basically expect something like a device node (or 2), so I can assign one  node to virtualbox "serial port" settings and assign the other node to my linux applicatio that is currently running on the linux host.

Thank you for your help

EDIT: it looks like `socat` might be the tool for the job , but I can't quite grab the way it works. I am trying the command:

```
socat -d -d PTY:link=/home/nass/acm0,raw,echo=0 UNIX-CONNECT:/home/nass/dm0 

2013/07/18 17:53:56 socat[13271] N PTY is /dev/pts/10
2013/07/18 17:53:56 socat[13271] N opening connection to AF=1 "/home/nass/dm0"
2013/07/18 17:53:56 socat[13271] E connect(5, AF=1 "/home/nass/dm0", 16): Connection refused
2013/07/18 17:53:56 socat[13271] N exit(1)
```

Why is the connection refused? 
If `/home/nass/dm0` is missing, the virtual machine will fail to startup (both in host pipe and host device cases)

I pre-created the node /home/nass/dm0 as a file with `touch /home/nass/dm0`. how should I setup virtualbox? host device? host pipe?

should dm0 even exist before powering up the virtual machine? if yes, should it be a file created with `touch /home/nass/dm0`? If it should be a socket, how do I pre-create it?

Comment: Have you checked how you can add serial ports to your VM? There are a couple of settings.

Comment: @JeffRSon I was doing that currently as a matter of fact. Now i am reading up on `socat` suggested by virtualbox manual. I am still puzzled as to how to integrate the addresses established by `socat` to my code.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old question, but I was recently working with socat and virtual serial ports and this cropped up in a google search.

If you want `socat` to *create* the unix socket, then use `UNIX-LISTEN` instead of `UNIX-CONNECT`:

```
socat pty,link=/home/nass/acm0,raw,echo=0 unix-listen:/home/nass/dm0
```

Running the above produces a pty device with a symlink at `$HOME/acm0`:

```
$ ls -l ~/acm0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 lars lars 10 Jan 12 23:12 /home/lars/acm0 -> /dev/pts/8
```

And a Unix socket at `$HOME/dm0`:

```
$ ls -l ~/dm0
srwxr-xr-x 1 lars lars 0 Jan 12 23:12 /home/lars/dm0
```

If you connect to the unix socket and send data, it will be sent out the pty device (and vice-versa). This works, but it may not be what you want. If your Linux application expects to interact with a serial port, then instead of a unix socket you would want a second pty device:

```
socat pty,link=$HOME/vmside,raw,echo=0 pty,link=$HOME/hostside,raw,echo=0
```

This creates a pair of connected pty devices (one named `vmside` and one named `hostside`). You would connect the `vmside` pty to your virtual machine, and then you would connect your application (or other serial communication program, like `picocom` or `cu` or `screen`) to `hostside`.

Comment: soory man, not working on that project anymore to test this out ! :)

Comment: Yeah, no worries; the answer wasn't so much for you but for other folks who find their way here via google :).